# Socket.io doesn't reconnect after connection lost - React Native + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, react-native, websocket, socket.io

**CLIENT**

On the react native client side, I'm using socket.io-client version 2.1.1 and I have included socket.io like this:

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
socket = io('MY_SERVER_URL', {jsonp: false});
```

*Mycomponent.js* component looks like this

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {}

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
     socket.connect() // code for reconnecting
     console.log('disconnected...')
  });

  socket.on('someEvent',this.someEventFunction)
}

render(){
  return(
   <Button onPress={socket.emit('someEvent','testData')} title="Event button"/>
  )
}
```

**SERVER**

On the server, I'm using socket.io version 2.3.0 and this is the code

```
io.on('connection', (socket)=> {

    socket.on('someEvent',(data) => {
      socket.emit(data)     
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
      socket.disconnect();
    })

});
```

**THE PROBLEM**

When the connection terminates(I manually terminate the node.js server), It fires the disconnect event on Mycomponent.js *(ie the console.log writes that 'disconnected...')*. But when I turn on the node.js server connection again, the the client and server doesn't seem to be connected. (this is to say the 'someEvent' dont work anymore)

It is like the **socket.connect()** doesn't work or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

**WHAT I WANT**

If a connection is lost, I need the client to try reconnecting again and again. And if it succeed to reconnect, I need other events to continue working as normal.

How do I solve this?